# Pass by reference in objective c

Tags: objective-c, pass-by-reference

I am a calling c++ method from objective c:

**C++ Method:**

```
void TestMethod( size_t& outputSize,
                 OutputArray& outputArray );
```

**Objective C:**

```
-(void) testMethodObjc : outputSize,
       OutputArrayObjc : outputArray
{

     TestMethod( outputSize, [outputArray getArray ]);
}
```

How do I accomplish this? I hear from other postings that objective-c does not support pass by reference.

Comment: Undo is right, here is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892520/passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to - Obj-C is a strict subset of C. Just make sure that the file the code is in is a `.mm` file - not just `.m`

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C, like C, does not support pass by reference.

Like C, you can take the address of the variable and pass a pointer instead. And to manipulated the original variable in the function you would need to dereference the pointer.