# NSImage memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

First of all: I already searched on google and SO for solutions - none worked.
I've got an application which loads the artwork of the current iTunes track and displays it; this is stored in a NSImage instance, among some other variables, in a class:

```
@interface infoBundle : NSObject
 @property (strong) NSImage *track_artwork;
 @property (weak) NSString *track_title;
 @property (weak) NSString *track_album;
 @property (weak) NSString *track_artist;
@end
```

Then, an instance of this class is created:

```
-(infoBundle*)returnInfoBundle {
 infoBundle* tmpBundle = [[infoBundle alloc]init];
 tmpBundle.track_artwork = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:[(iTunesArtwork *)[[[iTunes currentTrack] artworks] objectAtIndex:0] rawData]];
 [...]
 return tmpBundle;
}
```

And later used:

```
-(void)iTunesDidChange {
 infoBundle* tmpBundle = [self returnInfoBundle];
 [...]
 [imageView setImage:tmpBundle.track_artwork];
}
```

That's eating up ~2MB (Cover size, I'd guess) per call of iTunesDidChange.

I already tried:

- [tmpBundle autorelease];
- [tmpBundle release];
- [tmpBundle dealloc];
- tmpBundle = nil;

and, after that didn't help:
 - Enabling ARC.

=> Why is this eating up memory, although the object (tmpbundle) should get removed?
=> How may I achieve leak-less NSImage usage?

Thanks for any tips/suggestions/solutions :)

Comment: Tip for next time: Try using Instruments to debug performance issues like these, much more helpful about other aspects of your application and quicker.

Comment: `tempBundle.track_artwork`looks like a typo?

Comment: @duci9y did that. However, I found the information provided by Instruments not very helpful. Detailed, indeed, but not helpful.

Comment: @mikeD where is that typo? :)

Comment: It'd always be useful. Maybe we could help you interpret the results.

Comment: You don't present tmpBundle, only tmpbundle. Opps, my typo, too. Anyway, the uppercase B is confusing.

Comment: Also, please read this guide and name your methods and variables properly https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html . This is the third time today I'm advising someone to read it.

Comment: Create a property of `infoBundle* tmpBundle`, and use it when you need. After you are done with it, you release and set it to `nil`

Comment: @3r1d I already am setting tmpBundle to nil. Can you give me a code-example, please, as I guess I misunderstand your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You will have a memory leak if you create your object on your method and not release it inside that method or you have to reference it when you pass it as a parameter by reference :  [Passing arguments by value or by reference in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892520/passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference-in-objective-c)

Your problem is that you are creating an instance of `infoBundle` two times, and when you are initializing another instance of it, you are leaving the first one without reference, so it remains in memory, and without connection to remove it (**memory leak**).

## Solution

To make your things easier you should create an instance of your object

```
@implementation
{
    infoBundle* tmpBundle;
}
```

Use it where ever you need it

```
-(infoBundle*)returnInfoBundle 
{
    tmpBundle = [[infoBundle alloc]init];
    tmpBundle.track_artwork = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:[(iTunesArtwork *)[[[iTunes currentTrack] artworks] objectAtIndex:0] rawData]];
    [...]
    return tmpBundle;
}

-(void)iTunesDidChange 
{
    tmpBundle = [self returnInfoBundle];
    [...]
    [imageView setImage:tmpBundle.track_artwork];
}
```

And when you are finished with that object dealloc will automatically release it if you add it to dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [tmpBundle release];
    tmpBundle = nil;
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just modifiy this line :-

```
  infoBundle* tmpBundle = [[[infoBundle alloc]init]autorelease];
```

Comment: Sadly, I just activated ARC which doesn't allow [* autorelease]; :(

Comment: Ok then remove autorelease.

Answer (score -1):

I can’t tell from your code what you are doing in [imageView setImage:tmpbundle.track_artwork]; but you may be having the same problem I had.

I was using

```
self.imageToDisplay  = [UIImage imageNamed:pictFileName];
```

and kept getting leaks. I switched to

```
self.imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pictFile];
```

and they went away.

According to the documentation for imageNamed,

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists… If you have an
>   image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it
>   does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create
>   your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your
>   single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving
>   the memory use characteristics of your app.

It sounds like you have either the same or a similar issue.

Comment: How do you use UIImage in developing a Cocoa application?

Comment: If Cocoa doesn’t use UIImage, then he has a different problem than I did. My point was that  UIImage:imageNamed caches the files and causes leaks. UIImage:imagewithContentsOfFile doesn’t cache the image so there is no leaking. I couldn’t tell from his code how he displays the image, so I thought he might have a similar problem.

Comment: Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are two different things, silly.